# ParsePush throws Exception 400 in Unity

Tags: c#, exception, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I have written a function to send a push notification request to the server. I am using Unity with Parse. When I send the request I get a Parse.ParseException: 400: bad request.

The idea is to send a notification to one player letting them know they have been attacked by another player. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
Debug.Log ("<color=#ffa500ff> Sending Push Notification </color>");
    string pushMsg = "You were attacked by " + ServerData.Instance.my_player.username;
    if(!ServerData.Instance.PVP.pvpOpponentData.attackerWon)
        pushMsg += " and lost the fight.";
    else
        pushMsg += " and you won the fight!";

    Debug.Log(pushMsg);

    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.Query = ParseInstallation.Query.WhereEqualTo("player",ParseObject.CreateWithoutData("player",ServerData.Instance.PVP.pvpOpponentData.targetObjectId));
    push.Data = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        {"title", ServerData.Instance.PVP.pvpOpponentData.bragMessage},
        {"alert", pushMsg}
    };
    push.SendAsync().ContinueWith(p =>
                                  {
        if(sUtil.isNotParseError(p))
        {
            Debug.Log ("<color=#ffa500ff> Push Notification Sent! </color>");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log ("<color=#ffa500ff> Push Notification Failed!\n" + p.Exception.Message + "</color>");
        }
    });
```